# CSS3 Pie Not Working in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, css, css3pie

***UPDATE***  This would appear to be a issue with `background` in IE8. CSS3 PIE appears to work correctly however when I have a background it doesn't show. If I remove the background css completely it shows again. IE:

```
html, body{ 
  background: /*CSS */; /* Remove this property */
}
```

Now my question turns into how do I get CSS3 PIE to work properly in IE 8 *with* a background?

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lynda333/2Vm8e/2/) with the above code.

---

### ***Original Question***

---

I am attempting to replicate a look in IE 8 using CSS3 Pie JS Edition. Here is what I want it to look like:

[image: Correct Look]

Here is the way it looks in IE 8 with CSS3 PIE:

[image: IE 8 Screenshot]

As you can see when I implement CSS3 PIE the box disappears! I have not used CSS3 PIE before and do not know what is wrong. Here is the code I am using:

***NOTE***: I am using the JS edition (I am using a hosted CMS and do not have server side access thus *cannot* use the `.htc` file.)

Here is my code to call CSS3 Pie:

```
<!--[if lt IE 10]>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/PIE.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
       if (window.PIE) {
         $('.surround').each(function() {
           PIE.attach(this);
          });
         }
       });
  </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Here is the HTML and CSS:

```
<div class="row surround">
<div class="twelvecol">
 <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
</div>

.surround
 {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  padding: 25px;
  background:#f5f2f7;
  border: 5px solid #b30005;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  -webkit-border-radius:25px;
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  -o-border-radius: 25px;
  border-radius:25px;
  border-top: solid #b30005 25px;
 }
```

Comment: Off-topic technical point: you should put the un-prefixed version of a CSS style last, after the prefixed versions.

Comment: why does the IE8 screenshot have a gap in the box where the rounded corner should be? that doesn't look right. if css3pie isn't working, I'd expect it to show a solid box, just like if you didn't have the rounded corners at all.

Comment: @Spudley - I have modified and re-worked my code. IE 8 now shows the bar all the way across but the same issue still appears. When I apply CSS3 PIE the class it is applied to is removed. I have edit my question to reflect the new code.

Comment: when CSS3Pie makes elements disappear completely, it is typically a `z-index` issue -- the css3pie website has detailed discussion of this topic in its known issues page. The solution typically involves adding z-index style, but also maybe `zoom:1` or other IE hacks.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm running into the same issue where setting a background color ruins IE8.

Comment: @ZachWolf - Not one that easily worked, it was such a hassle I dropped trying to make IE 8 look the same.

Comment: @Lynda I also ended up abandoning ie8. Having a solution like CSS3Pie to fix IE is actually too good to be true.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As @Spudley mentioned in a comment above the issue was a z-index issue as [described on the CSS3 PIE Website](http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/#z-index):

> **Disappearing backgrounds/borders/shadows (z-index issues)**
>
> First, a little background on how PIE renders CSS3 decorations: a single  element is created which holds all the VML objects. This container element is inserted as a previous sibling to the target element, and absolutely positioned at the same coordinates. If the target element is position:absolute or position:relative, then the css3-container element is given the same z-index as the target element, and since it is a previous sibling in the DOM tree it gets displayed behind, with no possibility of any other element sneaking in between.
>
> However, this does not work so well when the target element is position:static, because static elements do not participate in z-index stacking. The only way to make our position:absolute css3 element go behind it is to give it z-index:-1. Unfortunately, this has a bad side-effect: not only will the css3 element go behind the target element, it will also go behind the background of any ancestor element(s) which are themselves position:static. This leads to situations in which PIE creates the VML rendering correctly but it disappears behind a parent element's background.
>
> The only way I know of to work around this is to either:
>
> ```
>      make the target element position:relative, or
>      make the ancestor element position:relative and give it a z-index.
> ```
>
> Both of these workarounds can have potential unwanted side-effects in terms of child element positioning and z-index stacking. PIE could easily force one or the other itself, but:
>
> One or the other may be more appropriate depending on the particular situation, so the CSS author needs to be able to control which one gets chosen.
>       Forcing position:relative outside of the CSS would put IE out of sync with other browsers, leading to confusing inconsistencies.
>
> PIE therefore does neither, and it is up to the author to implement either workaround where necessary. In most cases simply adding position:relative to the target element is fine.

The solution can cause other issues. I ended up asking myself is it worth the hassle to create rounded corners? For some sites, yes it would be, for others, well it is your choice.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `behavior: url(PIE.htc);`, you can set `behavior: url(PIE.php);`.